# Optimize images with nginx

Tags: nginx, image-compression, google-pagespeed

I am getting very bad ratings with google page speed

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.benty-fields.com%2F&tab=desktop

the main problem seems to be to optimize images. I only use png and jpg, so I don't quite see the problem?
Anyway Google PageSpeed tells me

Properly formatting and compressing images can save many bytes of data.
Optimize the following images to reduce their size by 516.3KiB (60% reduction).

I am just wondering whether I better do this manually for the 4 images google is complaining about or is there a way to do this on my nginx server?
thanks
carl

Comment: Run your static images through an image optimizer like `optipng`; they can compress the images better.

Comment: Psst! Make sure you read and understand [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization?hl=en) before getting too intimate with nginx